# How do I send telnetlib control + ] command in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, telnet, telnetlib

I am trying to send `control + ]` command in python using telnetlib library.

Currently I am doing:

```
tn.write('^]')
```

and also

```
tn.write('\x1D')
```

which i got from http://donsnotes.com/tech/charsets/ascii.html

To type `control-A` I use `tn.write('\x01')` and it works so I am confused why `tn.write('\x1D')` is not working for `control-]`.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl-]` cannot be sent on the wire. You have to use a, let's say, synonym for it like `close()`

For further reading, see the pinpoint answer here: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-December/636929.html

Answer (score 0):

The ^] command is not actually sent to the server. It is a command to the telnet client.  When you run the `telnet` program (not related to python at all) you see:

```
~$ telnet localhost 2050
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

That means `^]` is a escape character. It is a way to make the local telnet program exit the input mode that sends everything to the server, and enter the input mode that accepts local commands. When you type `^]` in this case, the telnet program won't send it to the server, it will just change the input mode.

Since you're connecting using the telnet protocol directly to the server, and not using the telnet **program**, it doesn't make sense to send `^]`.